# Lock environment before fork()

Tags: rust

How do I lock the environment before forking to then spawn a new child on unix environments?

I have seen the `Command::spawn` method uses `env_lock()`, but I can't seem to find any information on that method.

Comment: I don't think fork care about that, it's probably internal detail for Rust side. But I can't say for sure

Comment: I think its used to block the env until it has finished starting the new child.